# Issues with checking an array moving both forwards and backwards simultaneously and issue printing values stored in a pointer array

Tags: c++

Preface: Currently reteaching myself C++ so please excuse some of my ignorance.

The challenge I was given was to write a program to search through a static array with a function and return the indices of the number you were searching for. This only required 1 function and minimal effort so I decided to make it more "complicated" to practice more of the things I have learned thus far. I succeeded for the most part, but I'm having issues with my if statements within my for loop. I want them to check 2 separate spots within the array passed to it, but it is checking the same indices for both of them. I also cannot seem to get the indices as an output. I can get the correct number of memory locations, but not the correct values. My code is somewhat cluttered and I understand there are more efficient ways to do this. I would love to be shown these ways as well, but I would also like to understand where my error is and how to fix it. Also, I know 5 won't always be present within the array since I'm using a pseudo random number generator.
Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std; 
    // This is supposed to walk throught the array both backwards and forwards checking for the value entered and
    // incrementing the count so you know the size of the array you need to create in the next function.
    int test(int A[], int size, int number) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++, size--)
        {
            if (A[i] == number)
                count++;
            // Does not walk backwards through the array. Why?
            if (A[size] == number)
                count++;
        }
        cout << "Count is: " << count << endl;
        return (count);
    }

    // This is a linear search that creates a pointer array from the previous "count" variable in function test.
    // It should store the indices of the value you are searching for in this newly created array.
    int * search(int A[], int size, int number, int arr_size){
        int *p = new int[arr_size];
        int count =0;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if(A[i]==number) {
                p[count] = i;
            }
            count++;
        }
        return p;
    }

    int main(){
        // Initializing the array to zero just to be safe
        int arr[99]={0},x;
        srand(time(0));

        // Populating the array with random numbers in between 1-100
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            arr[i]= (rand()%100 + 1);

    //    Was using this to check if the variable was actually in the array.
    //    for(int x : arr)
    //        cout << x << " ";

        // Selecting the number you wish to search for.
    //    cout << "Enter the number you wish to search for between 1 and 100: ";
    //    cin >> x;

    // Just using 5 as a test case.
        x = 5;

        // This returns the number of instances it finds the number you're looking for
        int count = test(arr, (sizeof(arr)/4), x);

    //    If your count returns 0 that means the number wasn't found so no need to continue.
        if(count == 0){
            cout << "Your number was not found " << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        // This should return the address array created in the function "search"
        int *index = search(arr, (sizeof(arr)/4), x, count);

        // This should increment through the array which address you assigned to index.
        for(int i=0; i < count; i++) {

            // I can get the correct number of addresses based on count, just not the indices themselves.
            cout << &index[i] << " " << endl;
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

I deeply appreciate your help and patience as well as I want to thank you again for your help.

Comment: `i <= size` fairly certain this should be `i < size`

Comment: There are multiple problems with this code and I can only answer one of the questions, so I will not post an answer but just note that putting out `&index[i]` gives you the address of the array element, whereas I think you want the content of the array element, which would be `index[i]`.